# How to keep Totino's Pizza Rolls from bursting in oven?

Tags: oven, temperature, pizza, cooking-time

Is there a way to keep Totino's Pizza Rolls from opening and spilling contents in the oven, or is that just what they do?

We normally cook half the bag at 425° for 14min, which is following the instructions on the bag almost completely (we add one minute because we like them well done).

Comment: ...no experience with the product, but maybe trying reducing the oven temp.

Comment: I've never tried these pizza rolls either, but stopping them exploding seems to be a hotly debated internet topic! The most promising suggestion I'm seeing is to bake at a lower temp (around 375), extending your cook time, and flip them half way through.

Comment: @mfox Ok thanks, definitely a will-try for next time ;)

Comment: The most common way to prevent it's big brother, the calzone, from bursting in the oven, is scoring the top to allow steam to escape. I'm not sure how effective that would be with pizza rolls as I have never had these, but you could try poking a tiny hole in the top to see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue for years, and only recently found the solution!
I just bought a microwave/convection/air fryer, and discovered when I heat the pizza rolls using the air fryer setting, the pizza rolls come out perfectly crispy, hot, and best of all, completely intact with all the filling!! Yay!! Hope it works for others who have struggled w this wonderful little snack

Answer (score 2):

I purchase them too.   I have found that allowing them to defrost for 30 minutes before the oven dramatically reduces explosions.

Comment: Does this affect the texture? I would imagine they might get a bit soggy if you let them defrost first.

Comment: No, they turn out perfect.   And they are not fully defrosted after 30 minutes.  I use the package directions.   425°, etc., except we do turn the pan once as our oven isn't the greatest.   We pull them out when they reach the color we want.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to preheat the oven and keep them in the freezer.  Do not let them thaw.  Follow the directions on the box/bag.  Flip half way through.  I eat them so much and had that same problem till i perfected it.